# swift decimal format to double format issue

Tags: swift

I have a textfield where I can write the an decimal-keypad a value like `25.00`
This value I save into CoreData (double format) => `Double(txtField.text!)!`
It works !

On an device, which is set to "Germany", the value Wille be `25,00`
But there I will get this error:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

(swift 5)

Where is my mistake?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `NumberFormatter` to parse the input from the text field. `NumberFormatter` correctly handles the different decimal separators used in different locales. The `Double` initialise accepting a `String` on the other hand does not handle decimal separators other than the decimal point.

`NumberFormatter` also defaults to the user's `Locale`, so you don't need to set its `locale` property when parsing user input.

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
if let numericInput = numberFormatter.number(from: txtField.text!)?.doubleValue {
    // handle the `Double` value here
}
```

Comment: thanks ! Is double the correct format in core data or should I use decimal ?

Comment: @Ghost108 that depends on what kind of values are you trying to represent. If you are trying to represent decimal numbers (such as prices), then use `Decimal`. If you are representing non-decimal floating point values, then use `Double`